# How can I add additional attributes to my Create Object AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am creating Subscribers using AMPScript in my Landing Page like this:

```
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @Email)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", @SubscriberStatus)
SET @statusCode = InvokeCreate(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode)
```

I know I need to create a new object like this

```
SET @attribute=CreateObject(Attribute)
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,'Name','First Name')
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,'Value','John')
```

But I don't know how to connect the two, there is a `AddObjectArrayItem` but I'm not sure where to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You connect the two by using the [AddObjectArrayItem() AMPScript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/addobjectarrayitem.htm).  The final code would look like the following.  Pay special attention to the second to the last line of code.

```
SET @attribute=CreateObject(Attribute)
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,'Name','First Name')
SetObjectProperty(@attribute,'Value','John')

SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @Email)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", @SubscriberStatus)
AddObjectArrayItem(@sub, "Attributes", @attribute)
SET @statusCode = InvokeCreate(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode)
```

Comment: The first line of your code is missing quotes around the _Attribute_ parameter. It should look like this:
`SET @attribute=CreateObject("Attribute")`